# NSURL URLWithString:relativeToURL: is clipping relative url

Tags: ios, url, nsurl

I'm trying to implement an iOS app, which uses RestKit. In all examples I've seen so far the following code is used to create the URLs:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.service.com/v1"];
NSURL *relativeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL];
```

But then `[relativeURL absoluteString]` will return `https://api.service.com/files/search`.

So I tried a few examples:

```
NSURL *baseURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.service.com/v1/"];
NSURL *baseURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.service.com/v1"];
NSURL *baseURL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/v1" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.service.com"]];

NSURL *relativeURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL1];
NSURL *relativeURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL2];
NSURL *relativeURL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL3];
NSURL *relativeURL4 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL1];
NSURL *relativeURL5 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL2];
NSURL *relativeURL6 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"files/search" relativeToURL:baseURL3];

NSLog(@"1: %@", [relativeURL1 absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"2: %@", [relativeURL2 absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"3: %@", [relativeURL3 absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"4: %@", [relativeURL4 absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"5: %@", [relativeURL5 absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"6: %@", [relativeURL6 absoluteString]);
```

And this is the output:

```
1: https://api.service.com/files/search
2: https://api.service.com/files/search
3: https://api.service.com/files/search
4: https://api.service.com/v1/files/search
5: https://api.service.com/files/search
6: https://api.service.com/files/search
```

So the only example returning what I want is #4. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I read [[RFC1808]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808) which defines the normative algorithm for resolving relative URLs

2 issues:

1. the relative url may not start with a / or it is considered to be absolute:

   ```
    Step 4: If the embedded URL path is preceded by a slash "/", the
       path is not relative and we skip to Step 7."
   ```
2. when the base url ends with a non-slash. everything from the last slash on is skipped

   ```
    Step 6: The last segment of the base URL's path (anything
       following the rightmost slash "/", or the entire path if no
       slash is present) is removed and the embedded URL's path is
       appended in its place.  The following operations are
       then applied, in order, to the new path:"
   ```

so that explains it. the baseURL needs to end in a / and the relative url shouldn't start with a /

Comment: @downvoter please explain why ... is it because of the leading /? I get that and therefore edited it and up voted mike.. but please leave comment whenever you down vote

Comment: again: latest down voter would you please leave a comment so I can fix it if needed

Comment: the baseURL needs to end in a / and the relative url shouldn't start with a / this is absolutely correct:). I was struggling with some problem wrt base url and path. Can you add the link for [RFC1808]

Answer (score 9):

You have two problems here:

Firstly, the string `/files/search` is an *absolute* path since it starts with a slash. Resolving it against any existing URL will ignore the existing path.

Secondly, `https://api.service.com/v1` does not have a trailing slash to indicate it's a directory. Any strings resolved against it will always ignore the `v1` portion.

To conclude, you need that combo of a relative path — `files/search` — and directory base URL — `https://api.service.com/v1/`.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
//it's right
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"getValidNumber" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dns.test.com:22009/service/"]]; 

//error
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"getValidNumber" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dns.test.com:22009/service/"]]; 

//error
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/getValidNumber" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dns.test.com:22009/service"]];
```

`
The 'http://' is necessary to use this method.