# URL init(string:relativeTo:) works wrong

Tags: ios, swift, url, path, nsurl

I'm trying to build a compound url in 3 steps, but the result is wrong!

```
// 1)
let baseURL = URL(string: "http://clapps.clappsa.com")!
print(baseURL.absoluteString)
// http://clapps.clappsa.com

// 2)
let extendedURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("public", isDirectory: true)
print(extendedURL.absoluteString)
// http://clapps.clappsa.com/public/

// 3)
let finalURL = URL(string: "/img/3-mentee.jpg", relativeTo: extendedURL)!
print(finalURL.absoluteString)
// http://clapps.clappsa.com/img/3-mentee.jpg
```

Expected result:

```
http://clapps.clappsa.com/public/img/3-mentee.jpg
```

Even if I try to use the `absoluteURL` of the `extendedURL` like this:

```
let finalURL = URL(string: "/img/3-mentee.jpg", relativeTo: extendedURL.absoluteURL)!
print(finalURL.absoluteString)
// http://clapps.clappsa.com/img/3-mentee.jpg
```

I will get the same result.

Strange, but such approach works ok with some other different URLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove first `/` to get expected result:

```
let finalURL = URL(string: "img/3-mentee.jpg", relativeTo: extendedURL)!
print(finalURL.absoluteString) // http://clapps.clappsa.com/public/img/3-mentee.jpg
```

More detail explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582586/2463616).